# Windows 7 often does not respond on the first click

Tags: windows-7, mouse, mouse-click

I think the Windowing interface in my Windows 7 installation may be sick. Desktop icons and buttons in programs and the window close button often do not respond on the first click.  Now and then they do. Open up Task Manager, and click on  Image Name column header the first time does not cause the column to change sort order; its takes a second click.

I don't see any task consuming more than 1% of the CPU in Task Manager.

What can cause this?

I've tried rebooting.

I am using Microsoft Wireless Notebook Optical Mouse.

Comment: Perhaps your mouse batteries are dying?

Comment: Try reinstalling your mouse driver. I would also check your optical receiver for any damage. What is the average distance between your mouse and the receiver? Is it on the side opposite of your mouse hand? Do you have any other wireless devices plugged into your laptop that may be interfering?

Comment: Have you tried a different mouse?